# Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null in a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, getelementbyid

I have created a simple Javascript slider with Slice and Box effects.
It runs and no problem. But when i look up console, I see that after two cycles it throws an error. Browser says that document.getElementById('smth') cannot get specified element. What may be the problem?
Below is codepen URL. [Slider](https://codepen.io/Gurbanov/pen/QEKgRj/)

```
script
```

Comment: It happens at `timer=setInterval(function(){ pictures.closeIt(document.getElementById('divin'+(i-1)).childNodes, 0)},0);` line. Make sure you ave an element with the dynamically generated id of `"divin" +(i-1)`

Comment: I know it appears at that line, spent 2 days but couldnt find anythink causing this. I am sure i have generated an element with that id. Very interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `pictures.sliceIt` function when the `i` argument becomes 5 the dynamically generated `id` in the below line becomes `divin4` and apparently it's the source of the problem.

```
timer=setInterval(function(){ pictures.closeIt(document.getElementById('divin'+(i-1)).childNodes, 0)},0);
```

I just changed the above code to

```
timer=setInterval(function(){ pictures.closeIt(document.getElementById('divin'+(i-1)%4).childNodes, 0)},0);
```

and it stops complaining.

Comment: Now it works without error, but one problem arises. Pictures doesn't follow each other as intended. The fifth picture stays a while and suddenly changes to another picture without effect.